# Touching the Klaf of the Torah not while reading it

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, kavod, hagbah-gelilah

Is there a distinction made between during Torah reading and not during Torah reading in regards to the halacha to not touch the klaf (parchment) of a Torah scroll directly? I have seen people use their tallis when grabbing the klaf during glilah in order to straighten the klaf being wrapped, but I have also seen many God-fearing Jews touch it directly. Does anyone know a source that discusses this?

Comment: ShA OC 147:1. Seems pretty clearly Asur.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/05/24/touching-sefer-torah-with-bare-hands/) with its cross-refs to Shulchan Aruch:

> What are the dinim concerning mistakingly touching the klaf of the
>   Sfer Torah:
>
> 1. when kissing it with one’s tziztis
> 2. when doing glila
>
> Answer:
>
> In both cases one should be careful not to touch the Sefer Torah with
>   bare hands. The Gemara writes that one who touches the parchment of
>   the Sefer Torah with bare hands loses the mitzvah he was doing (such
>   as hagbahah; see Shulchan Aruch 147 and Mishnah Berurah).
>
> One who does touch the parchment inadvertantly does not need to take
>   any further action.

Answer (score 1):

Yalkut Yosef (147:1) writes that there is no distinction:

> אסור לאחוז בספר תורה בגוף הקלף או הגויל בלי מטפחת, **בין כשגולל את
>   הספר תורה בעת קריאת התורה בצבור, ובין כשגולל הספר תורה בינו לבין
>   עצמו**, והחמירו חכמים הרבה מאד בזה, ואמרו, שכל האוחז ספר תורה ערום בלי
>   מטפחת נקבר ערום בלא אותה מצוה שעשה בעת אחיזתו, אם זו קריאה, או גלילה,
>   וצריך להזהר מאד בזה. ולכן מנהגינו להניח מפה על הספר תורה, כדי שלא
>   לאחוז בידים את גוף הספר תורה בעת שמברך, אלא בהפסק מטפחת. וכן נהגו בכמה
>   בתי כנסת מקדמת דנא. וגם כשרוצה לגלול הספר תורה באמצע הקריאה, כדי
>   להמשיך לקרוא בעמוד הבא, לא יגלול אלא במטפחת. [ילקוט יוסף, חלק ב', ספר
>   על הלכות קריאת התורה ובית הכנסת, עמוד רא, ובהוספות ומילואים שבמהדורת
>   תשס''ד, עמוד שפט].